# VS Item Template Compiled Custom Parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, t4, visual-studio-templates

I would like to create a custom parameter for a vstemplate containing some C# code. Basically I want to put `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")` in my template (the formatted date, not the code). Basically I want to achieve the equivalent of the T4 below in my item template.

```
[Migration(<#= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") #>)]
public class $fileinputname$ : Migration
```

Is this possible? Or is there a simple way to use a T4 as the template file for my vstemplate item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this with standard VSTemplates. In order to get C# output in to your template you need to create a wizard so you can populate your own parameters for the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is any way to add a date in that format using visual studio templates.  According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx), your only date/time options are `YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00`.

Comment: It's not `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00`. According to the docs it's dependant upon your Windows settings. `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00` is just an example. However it always seems to be `MM/DD/YYYY 00:00:00` (i.e. US format) for me despite having the Windows regional format set to "English (United Kingdom)".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is in code templates. I think this is what you're after: http://theoldsewingfactory.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/code-templates-for-migratordotnet/